# Maintaining attendance logs of employees between given date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'checkin_checkout' that stores records of user's attendance logs and a 'user' table that stores basic information about users.

User:

```
id | name | username | password 
1  | Jack | jack123  | jackPwd
2  | John | John1234 | john!23
3  | Jill | Jill123  | jill123
```

checkin_checkout:

```
id | users_id | checkin_time  | checkout_time  | is_delayed_checkin | is_early_checkout | locked
1  | 1        | 2014-09-22 9:0| 2014-09-22 18:0|    0               |  0                    0
2  | 2        | 2014-09-22 9:5| 2014-09-22 18:5|    0               |  0                    0
3  | 1        | 2014-09-23 9:0| 2014-09-23 18:8|    0               |  0                    0
4  | 2        | 2014-09-23 9:7| 2014-09-23 18:9|    0               |  0                    0
5  | 3        | 2014-09-23 9:0| 2014-09-23 18:0|    0               |  0                    0
```

To display attendance logs between two dates, say, 2014-09-22 to 2014-09-23, the view is as follows :

```
Emp_Name | Checkin_date | Check-in_time | Checkout_date | Checkout_time
Jack     | 2014-09-22   | 09:0          | 2014-09-22    | 18:0
Jack     | 2014-09-23   | 09:0          | 2014-09-23    | 18:8
John     | 2014-09-22   | 09:5          | 2014-09-22    | 18:5
John     | 2014-09-23   | 09:7          | 2014-09-23    | 18:9
Jill     | 2014-09-23   | 09:0          | 2014-09-23    | 18:0
```

If there is no record found for the user within that particular date range, then 'Absent' is displayed (only if zero record is found)

```
Jill     | Absent       |               |               |
```

What is required is to display also the record for 2014-09-22 in case of Jill, and display some appropriate message, like:

```
Jill     | 2014-09-22   | N/A           | 2014-09-22    | N/A (which is not displayed in current case)
Jill     | 2014-09-23   | 09:0          | 2014-09-23    | 18:0
```

The sql query :

```
BEGIN
select fullname,DATE(checkin_time) 
as checkin_date,TIME(checkin_time) 
as checkin_time,DATE(checkout_time) 
as checkout_date ,TIME(checkout_time) 
as checkout_time,early_checkout_remarks,
delayed_checkin_remarks 
from 
(select
users.id,concat(users.firstname,' ',users.lastname)  
as fullname,checkin_time,checkout_time,total_time_elapsed 
as time_spent,early_checkout_remarks,delayed_checkin_remarks

 from

users

LEFT JOIN checkin_checkout

ON users.id=checkin_checkout.users_id

AND DATE(checkin_time) between date(start_date)

AND date(end_date) WHERE users.deleted IS NULL 
order by id,firstname)


as t1 group by checkin_date,fullname;
 END
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you mean that if an employee is not present you want to display a note saying they weren't in instead of their checkout_time (since this value would be null or zero)?

Comment: if the user hasn't checked in for any dates between say 2014-09-22 to 2014-09-23, there won't be any records for the user, and one record with 'Absent' is displayed.

John |  Absent 

What I want is that  something like:

    John | 2014-09-22 | Absent
    John | 2014-09-23 | Absent

Comment: You'll need to use `COALESCE` to detect `NULL` values in your `LEFT JOIN` and display 'Absent' instead